# (IO) WebSocket on React-Native

Tags: javascript, sockets, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to implement SocketIO on react-native without any success ..
i have this code so far :

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'ReactNative';
const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');
const socket = io(`192.168.1.12:1337/join/${res}`, {
    transports: ['websocket']
});
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected!');
});
```

I can't fins any relative tutorial or doc that works and i can't implement native WebSocket because my end server is in sails .. 
If you have experience or help i'm for it !

Thanks 
 Hugo

Answer (score 0):

Lately I made a project in which I intended to use socket.io and I had spent some time and successfully configured socket.io.

In the end I decided not to use it at all, but this is the working code on the client that I left off:

```
// need to be set before requiring socketio client
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native'

import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'

// jsonp - avoid manipulation of DOM
const socket = io(URI, { jsonp: false })

socket.on('news', function () {

  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' })

})
```

Comparing the code you've provided with this one, `{jsonp: false}` is missing in your code. Try to add that.

I am afraid I can't explain any further since I do not have that much of experience in this area.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that ! :)